# combinatorics chess game :

Tags: combinatorics

Chess game with a player played only  one game with another played. 
We havee 45 games between females
and 190 games between men.
Find the total number of games that there was a male vs female on that game.

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well (or at all) to questions like this that look like routine homework and which show no effort.  Moreover, it's quite hard to sort out what is being asked...I think it's possible to guess what you mean, but why make people guess?  Please edit your post for clarity and indicate what you have tried.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: This is not clearly written at all.  From the $45$ and $190$ I suspect this is a round robin tournament, but you don't say so.  Without that, there is no answer.  Maybe the first sentence is supposed to say that, but I can't understand it.

Comment: yes its a tournament. I have tried something but its not correct . i dont know how to start.  Any help  how do i start it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Assuming this is a [round robin tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament) where each player plays against each other player exactly once, the numbers $45$ and $190$ can be used to determine exactly how many women and men there are.

The number of games played between $n$ players in a round robin tournament is equal to $\binom{n}{2}$.

> Let $w$ represent the number of women and $m$ the number of men.  We recognize that $45 = \binom{w}{2}$ and $190 = \binom{m}{2}$.  What are $w$ and $m$?

Comment: Logically we can say , 45  women games => 90 female , 190 men games=> 380 male

With robin tournament EQ we find that w=10 and m=20,  Dont know what to do with these numbers. Its like  10 games are bw to women (90 women ) , and 20 games are bw to men (380 men)

Comment: Yes, $w=10$.  Reading your comment however I'm not sure you know what $w$ is... you said "90 female" in your comment.  Surely you don't think there are 90 different women in this tournament, do you?

Comment: oh. lol i thought that haha. so since we found w=10 and m=20,  so its 10 games between women , and 20 games between men. how we can find the games that  there was male vs female?

Comment: You still don't seem to understand what $w$ represents. $w$ is the number of female players. With ten women total you have a total of 45 games played exclusively between women.  Make sure you stop and understand why and make sure you understand what a round Robin tournament actually is.